# can i use js variables to call java methods in jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I want to use the user input to call some java methods in JSP page, I've done it like this, but got HTTP Status 500 Error on Apache Tomcat Server. Can anyone please explain this:

```
            if($('#portNumber').val().length<4)
            {
                $('#error').text("Invalid port number.");
                $('#errorMsg').css("display","block");
                $('#errorMsg').show().fadeOut(1800);
            }
            else
            {
                <%
                    try
                    {
                        ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(%>$('#portNumber').val()<%);
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        out.append("$('error').text('Exception: ');");
                    }
                %>
            }
```

Comment: *can i use js variables to call java methods in jsp?* No.

Comment: JSP runs on your server system. JavaScript runs on the client browser.

Comment: And embedded Java code like this, called *scriptlets*, has been discouraged for 15+ years.

Comment: any other idea about how to do this, like I want to use the input data from the same page to call a Java method

Comment: You make an AJAX call.

Comment: I've used this AJAX call, but it shows some parentheses missing after arguments list, I just can't find the culprit:   var port = $("#portNumber").val();
                    $.get("serverServlet",{portNum:port},function(response){
                        $("#logs").append(response);
                    });